# Strange SVG / javascript behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I might be missing something essential here.

I am changing the date format in some SVG text elements with this function.

```
jQuery.fn.fixDateformat = function(){
        ar = $(this).text().split("/")
        output = [ar[1], ar[0], ar[2]].join(".")
        $(this).text(output)
    };
```

In the console I get an array of the elements I want to change.

```
> array = $("text[x='0']")
[
<text y=​"5" dy=​".71em" text-anchor=​"middle" x=​"0">​04/21/13​</text>​, 
<text y=​"5" dy=​".71em" text-anchor=​"middle" x=​"0">​04/26/13​</text>​, 
<text y=​"5" dy=​".71em" text-anchor=​"middle" x=​"0">​05/02/13​</text>​, 
<text y=​"5" dy=​".71em" text-anchor=​"middle" x=​"0">​05/08/13​</text>​, 
<text y=​"5" dy=​".71em" text-anchor=​"middle" x=​"0">​05/14/13​</text>​
]
```

When I  pass the function to one of elements it works. Yeay!

```
> array.first().fixDateformatOnCharts()
```

But, when I loop through the array I get this error.

```
> array.each(function(i,v){ v.fixDateformatOnCharts()})
TypeError: Object #<SVGTextElement> has no method 'fixDateformatOnCharts'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `$(v)` to convert an element `v` to a jQuery object.

```
array.each(function(i,v){ $(v).fixDateformatOnCharts(); });
```

Maybe it would be better to add this funcionality to the plugin itself:

```
jQuery.fn.fixDateformat = function() {
  return this.each(function(i, el) {
    ar = $(el).text().split("/");
    output = [ar[1], ar[0], ar[2]].join(".");
    $(this).text(output);
  });
};
```

So you can use `array.fixDateformat();`.

Comment: Thanks that was it( and it was essential ;) )